# Mysterious variable

Tags: variables, actionscript, movieclip

I have analized all the code of a project, in one of it's classes there's a propertie(variable) that increments within a function, it is actually an animation step, and the only ways to play a mc's next frame is with gotoAndPlay, gotoAndStop, prevFrame and nextFrame, but in the class it is just this..

```
public function hurt(_damage:Number):void
{
   animationStep:int;
   //trace("hurt", health, _damage)
   health-=_damage
   if(health <= 0)
   {
      kill=true
      health=0
  }
  animationStep=5 - health
  trace(animationStep);
}
```

so what makes flash know that animationStep is a way of animating a mv if it's only an integer var?

Comment: It appears that changing that variable will make the increment (step) slower as the health decreases.  The only odd thing I see is that the animationStep is reset every time it runs.

Comment: the only way I know to animate a movieclip is using gotoAndPlay, ect

Comment: That's fine, but set up the variable in the beginning as a global.  Outside of the frame handlers.

Comment: so why the compiler knows that the variable must be passed as a parameter into the gotoAndPlay, function?

Comment: No.  Because that would make it local to the function.  If you plan on doing that, then pass it in, and use return to send the new value.

Comment: so when you make global variables the compiler automactically knows that it has to be passed into an unkown function?

Answer (score 0):

I'm setting this up as an answer because it is becoming a discussion.

It appears that changing that variable will make the increment (step) slower as the health decreases. The only odd thing I see is that the animationStep is reset every time it runs

Michael Jose:  the only way I know to animate a movieclip is using gotoAndPlay, ect –  Michael Jose 4 mins ago

That's fine, but set up the variable in the beginning as a global. Outside of the frame handlers.

Michael Jose:  so why the compiler knows that the variable must be passed as a parameter into the gotoAndPlay, function?

No. Because that would make it local to the function. If you plan on doing that, then pass it in, and use return to send the new value.

Comment: As per above comment:  If it's global, it can be modified anywhere.  So yes.  The compiler will know what to do with it.  You don't need to pass it, assuming your function itself is also global (which the goto functions are).